# Regex to validate String like C# does

Tags: c#, regex

I have this pattern to validate that if a string is correct or not.

```
public string isStringConstant(string vPart)
        {
            string pattern = @"^\""[\\(t|r|n|0|b|f|""|a|v|')a-zA-Z0-9,\.\*/;\~!\{\}@#\$%\^:&\(\)\+\[\]<>_\?=\-`]*\""$"; 
        Regex obj = new Regex(pattern);
        if (obj.IsMatch(vPart))
        {
            return "StringConstant";
        }
        return "INVALID";
    }
```

It works well but it also validates the following string which it should not.

```
 "harisnabeel\"
```

The input string source is a text file.

What wrong I am doing with that pattern?

Comment: Why should it not?

Comment: What makes a string correct?

Comment: Because that is how C# works.. You can not initialize string  `s = "abc\" ` in C#.. If you do , then it says "represents text as a sequence of utf-16" and does not let you initialize the variable.. @Thefourthbird

Comment: `It works well but it also validates the following string which it should not. string s = "harisnabeel\"` But apparently it doesn't. As you stated--this will not compile.

Comment: Nothing. I was just making the question clear to @Thefourthbird that ` string s = "abc\" `  is not valid in C#.   @Jawad

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the question because it was not clear. The string is coming from a text file.. @Barns

Comment: The problem is not the string or its source (the text file). The issue must be with the regex you are using or how you are using it. Could you post of the code where you try to validate the text?

Comment: posted. @SBFrancies

Answer (score 2):

Look at this part: \\(t|r|n|0|b|f|""|a|v|')

You are trying to shortcut having to write out \t\r\n, etc. In the process you have \, which says \ is a valid character in your string. Rewrite your "or this or that" portion long hand and you should be fine. Don't have time to test this personally, but a bit of experimentation with that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If we follow the title (*Regex to validate String like C# does*), the full regex should be:

```
// https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#string-literals
// A character that follows a backslash character (\) in 
// a regular_string_literal_character must be one of the following 
// characters: ', ", \, 0, a, b, f, n, r, t, u, U, x, v. 
// Otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

var rx = new Regex(@"^""(\\(?:['""\\0abfnrtv]|u[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}|U[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}|x[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})|[^\\""]+)*""$");
```

All the `""` are double, because the regex is based on a string-literal (`@"..."`), so they became a single `"` each.

Note the ending `[^\\""]` that becomes `[^\\"]` because the string is a literal string, so any character that isn't an escape `\` or a `"` (the `\` is handled separately, the unescaped `"` is the ending of the string). Note even the doubling of the `\\`, because otherwise a single `\` becomes an escape sequence of the regex, and the handling of `\x`, `\u` and `\U`.

Example of use:

```
var res = rx.Match(@"""Hello\nWorld\\\""\x123G""");
```

The "pieces" of the string:

```
var pieces = res.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().ToArray();
```

In this case `Hello`, `\n`, `World`, `\x123`, `G`